# Creating file and writing to it in one single command

Tags: linux

right now, I'm doing the following operation, which takes me two iterations of typing into my ubuntu terminal.

```
$ touch someFile
$ ls > SomeFile
```

Using `ls` here is just an example of some program that outputs some text.

It seems a bit tedious that I need to first create the file, and then write to it, is there any way I can do this in one go, something along these lines (which does not work):

```
$ ls > touch ff
```

Thanks a lot for any tips

Comment: This has got nothing to do with programming; should you choose to migrate it to e.g. [unix.se] or [su] please make sure you at least get the spelling right.  Your first two commands I'd expect to create **two different files**, `someFile` and `SomeFile`, the first of which should be empty. And the `ls > SomeFile` actually does exactly what you're asking - it creates `SomeFile` and populates it with the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to create the file first before writing to it.

Just simply:

```sh
$ ls
$ echo "asdf" > myFile 
$ ls
myFile
$ cat myFile
asdf
```

Here is a [reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/299219/HOW-TO-SAVE-THE-OUTPUT-OF-A-COMMAND-TO-A-FILE-IN-BASH-AKA-THE-LINUX-AND-MACOS-TERMINAL/) that explains this in more detail